# How can I change the connection for current tab in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ide, ssms

I want to run a query in SQL Server Management Studio on several databases on different servers.

I am already connected to these servers in the object explorer.

Is there a quick way to change the connection of the current query tab to a different server without the need to login again (without using change connection) and without opening a new tab.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Right-click in the query window and select `Connection > Change Connection`:

[image]

That will bring up the standard connection dialog from which you can connect to whatever other server / instance you want ...

Comment: Thanks but I was asking if there is an option without having to login again - which is what I need to do with change connection.

Comment: @Daniel: you can switch between databases on the same server with `USE (databasename)`, but there's no function to switch between **servers** other than using that connection dialog, as far as I know

Comment: The OP said he was already connected to the desired server and it was displayed in Object Explorer. He also said he didn't want to log in again. This answer does not address the OP's question.

Comment: Yea, the OP specifically did *not* want this answer: "without using change connection"