# connect to specific DB on a specific machine in SSMS

Tags: sql-server

I have DB machine M1 (Dev.)  hosting databases : DB1 , DB2, DB3 and having another setup for test M2, hosting the databases : DB1, DB2, DB3.

Now had connected to these 2 machines in SSMS. I can switch to the DB on the latter machine that was connected  using  the below command "Use ".
What is the way to switch to another machine and connect to the relavent DB's in SSMS.

I found a way by going to the object explorer and select the relevant object on a specific DB under specific env (right Click on specific table -> select Top 1000 rows). Is there any other approach like the "use" command or any other efficient approach.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? do you want to execute same select query on multiple databases on multiple servers?

Comment: are you asking how to switch between m1 and m2 similar like `use command`..you are using for databases?

Comment: Your question looks similar to this [Post already answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26200677)

Comment: Yes am looking to switch the connection from m1 to m2, without actually again reconnecting it. Is there a command similar to use or is it that i have to go only with the below approach posted in the link

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways

1. Using linked servers
   [image]

[image]

2. Right-click in the query window and select Connection > Change Connection:

[image]

That will bring up the standard connection dialog from which you can connect to whatever other server / instance you want ...